# Should I use T foo[X] instead of T *foo if x is know at compile-time?

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

Assuming this:

```
struct A
{
    char *a;
        char *b;
}
```

If I know size of `a` and `b` at compile-time is worth effort if I do use a fixed-array-size instead of or will it change nothing? it will save a lot of malloc calls, much of them in a loop and I think it's fastest.

```
struct A
{
    char a[256];
    char b[32];
};
```

Comment: If you now the size at compile time, you should use it for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Honestly char* and T* are *way* different questions. Polymorphism doesn't apply with primitives.

Comment: Do you know the _exact_ size or the _maximum_ size? Allocating 256 characters when the average string is 5.7 characters can be rather wasteful.

Comment: I know maximum allowed size of `a` and exact size of `b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can do everything with the second option that you want to do, then it's a better option. You should avoid dynamic memory allocation unless it's necessary. There are some reasons to go with the first option. The obvious one is that you might have a variable size, but you've indicated that that isn't the case. Here are some other reasons:

1. You might want to reassign `a` and `b`, which can be done with pointers but not arrays.
2. You might want to be able to efficiently *move* an `A` object.